# SQL Server how to insert into a table from linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have my local database `prova` and another database `SOFIADR`. I want to insert into the table `Events` of the `prova` database the rows of data retrieved from the linked database server `SOFIADR`. The database `SOFIADR` is a linked of my local database server `test`.

The following query in the database `NKSOFIA` works:

```
select *
from ARA_01.ARA01.dbo.monodosi_tab
```

If I move into my local database `prova` and try to import data in my table `events` I write:

```
insert into Events (.......)
    select field1, field2 .....
    from [SOFIADR].[NKSOFIA].ARA_01.ARA01.dbo.monodosi_tab
```

But I get an error:

> Msg 117, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   The object name 'SOFIADR.NKSOFIA.ARA_01.ARA01.dbo.monodosi_tab' includes an excessive number of prefixes. Maximum capacity is 3.

How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744878/error-when-insert-into-linked-server

Answer (score 1):

Use this syntax:

```
[LINKED SERVER].[DATABASE].[Schema].[TableName]
```

According to your pic:

```
[ARA2].[Database Name].[dbo].[monodosi_tab]
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to the differences between ORA and MS-SQL  use 
[LINKED SERVER].[USER_TABLE_SPACE (username)].[TableName]
or
[ARA_01]..[SOFIADR].[monodosi_tab]