# The object name contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2 while running the linked query

Tags: sql-server

I am writing a sql script in sql server that creates dynamic tables based on data. 
I was initially getting an error " The object name 'GBIPS-I-DB324D.CoreReferenceStaging.dbo.FinData2000_1' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2." while running the original query. GBIPS-I-DB324D is linked server object.

I tried to use execute statement and now getting an error  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'USE'.

Original Query

```
BEGIN
    set nocount on

declare @startYear int, @startQuarter int, @sql nvarchar(max), @tableName varchar(50);
set @startYear = 2000;
set @startQuarter = 1;
while(@startYear < 2018)
    begin
        set @startQuarter = 1;

        while(@startQuarter < 5)
        begin
            set @tableName = 'FinData' + cast(@startYear as varchar) + '_' + cast(@startQuarter as varchar);
            set @sql = '
                drop table [GBIPS-I-DB324D].[CoreReferenceStaging].[dbo].[' + @tableName + ']; 
                create table [GBIPS-I-DB324D].[CoreReferenceStaging].[dbo].[' + @tableName + '] ( calendarYear int, calendarQuarter int, companyid bigint not null, dataitemid bigint not null, dataitemvalue numeric(28,6), fiscalyear int, fiscalquarter int, periodenddate datetime, filingdate datetime, latestforfinancialperiodflag bit, latestfilingforinstanceflag bit );
                insert into [GBIPS-I-DB324D].[CoreReferenceStaging].[dbo].[' + @tableName + ']
                    select fp.calendarYear, fp.calendarQuarter, fp.companyid, fd.dataitemid, fd.dataitemvalue, fp.fiscalyear, fp.fiscalquarter, fi.periodenddate, fi.filingdate, fi.latestforfinancialperiodflag, fi.latestfilingforinstanceflag
                    from [Xpressfeed_dev].[dbo].[ciqFinPeriod] fp
                    inner join [Xpressfeed_dev].[dbo].[ciqFinInstance] fi on fi.financialPeriodId = fp.financialPeriodId
                    inner join [Xpressfeed_dev].[dbo].[ciqFinInstanceToCollection] fc on fc.financialInstanceId = fi.financialInstanceId
                    inner join [Xpressfeed_dev].[dbo].[ciqFinCollection] c on c.financialCollectionId = fc.financialCollectionId
                    inner join [Xpressfeed_dev].[dbo].[ciqFinCollectionData] fd on fd.financialCollectionId = c.financialCollectionId
                    where YEAR(fi.periodenddate) = ' + cast(@startYear as varchar) + ' and QUARTER(fi.periodenddate) = ' + cast(@startQuarter as varchar)
            EXEC sp_executesql @sql

            set @startQuarter += 1
        end
        set @startYear += 1;
    end
end
```

modified query

```
 BEGIN
    set nocount on

declare @startYear int, @startQuarter int, @sql nvarchar(max), @tableName varchar(50);
set @startYear = 2000;
set @startQuarter = 1;
while(@startYear < 2018)
    begin
        set @startQuarter = 1;

        while(@startQuarter < 5)
        begin
            set @tableName = 'FinData' + cast(@startYear as varchar) + '_' + cast(@startQuarter as varchar);
            set @sql = '
             EXECUTE (USE CoreReferenceStaging;drop table [dbo].[' + @tableName + ']) AT [GBIPS-I-DB324D]
             EXECUTE (USE CoreReferenceStaging;create table [dbo].[' + @tableName + '] ( calendarYear int, calendarQuarter int, companyid bigint not null, dataitemid bigint not null, dataitemvalue numeric(28,6), fiscalyear int, fiscalquarter int, periodenddate datetime, filingdate datetime, latestforfinancialperiodflag bit, latestfilingforinstanceflag bit )) AT [GBIPS-I-DB324D]

                insert into [GBIPS-I-DB324D].[CoreReferenceStaging].[dbo].[' + @tableName + ']
                    select fp.calendarYear, fp.calendarQuarter, fp.companyid, fd.dataitemid, fd.dataitemvalue, fp.fiscalyear, fp.fiscalquarter, fi.periodenddate, fi.filingdate, fi.latestforfinancialperiodflag, fi.latestfilingforinstanceflag
                    from [Xpressfeed_dev].[dbo].[ciqFinPeriod] fp
                    inner join [Xpressfeed_dev].[dbo].[ciqFinInstance] fi on fi.financialPeriodId = fp.financialPeriodId
                    inner join [Xpressfeed_dev].[dbo].[ciqFinInstanceToCollection] fc on fc.financialInstanceId = fi.financialInstanceId
                    inner join [Xpressfeed_dev].[dbo].[ciqFinCollection] c on c.financialCollectionId = fc.financialCollectionId
                    inner join [Xpressfeed_dev].[dbo].[ciqFinCollectionData] fd on fd.financialCollectionId = c.financialCollectionId
                    where YEAR(fi.periodenddate) = ' + cast(@startYear as varchar) + ' and QUARTER(fi.periodenddate) = ' + cast(@startQuarter as varchar)
            EXEC sp_executesql @sql

            set @startQuarter += 1
        end
        set @startYear += 1;
    end
end
```

Comment: Have you seen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744878/error-when-insert-into-linked-server ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, the 'USE' statement cannot be used when working with Linked Servers. This doesn't answer your question about the maximum of 2 but 'Use' is not the way to go. When there is no Linked Server in the game, you can use 'USE', but build the use-statement in the same statement that does the DML operation. You'll have to use Dynamic SQL for that which also have side-effects