# The object name 'AMAPHLINK.Payroll.dbo.EmpResignTb' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2

Tags: sql-server

I want to copy my table into `AMAPHLINK server`, but it keeps giving me an error.

```
select *
into AMAPHLINK.Payroll.dbo.[EmpResignTb]
from Payroll.dbo.EmpResignTb
```

**Error:**

> The object name 'AMAPHLINK.Payroll.dbo.EmpResignTb' contains more than
>   the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an error because you are not using a valid name.

The valid syntax is `server_name.database_name.schema_name.object_name` as referenced on the [MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) for INSERT.

Remove the incorrect schema and try again.

**Solution:**

Use square brackets "[]" around the name and remote database server

```
select *
into [AMAPHLINK].[Payroll].[dbo].[EmpResignTb]
from [Payroll].[dbo].[EmpResignTb]
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears this can't be done over linked servers.

You could create the table first then do an `INSERT INTO`.

The same question was asked here:
[error when insert into linked server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744878/error-when-insert-into-linked-server)